# Force the `Recipients` object to update when the To: text box has been edited

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I sort recipients when composing an email.

If I have 3 recipients (for example), run the sort macro, and then remove a recipient from the To: text box, running the macro a second time causes the removed recipient to re-appear. When I step through the macro on the second run, I can see that both `.CurrentItem.To` and the `Recipients` object still have all 3 recipients.

It is intermittent. Is there any way to force the `Recipients` object to update when the To: text box has been edited?

I can't find anything in the [Outlook VBA documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210995%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and trial and error has proved fruitless.

Code excerpt:

```vb
Public Sub SortRecipients()
    With Application.ActiveInspector
        If TypeOf .CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Debug.Print "Before: "
            Debug.Print "To: " & .CurrentItem.To
            Debug.Print "# of recipients: " & .CurrentItem.Recipients.Count

            ' Force an update if recipients have changed (DOESN'T HELP)
            .CurrentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll

            Set myRecipients = .CurrentItem.Recipients
            ' Create objects for To list
            Dim myRecipient As recipient
            Dim recipientToList As Object
            Set recipientToList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

            ' Create new lists from To line
            For Each myRecipient In myRecipients
                    recipientToList.Add myRecipient.Name
            Next

            ' Sort the recipient lists
            recipientToList.Sort
            ' Remove all recipients so we can re-add in the correct order
            While myRecipients.Count > 0
                myRecipients.Remove 1
            Wend

            ' Create new To line
            Dim recipientName As Variant
            For Each recipientName In recipientToList
                myRecipients.Add (recipientName)
            Next recipientName
            .CurrentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Add 4 recipients to the "To" line of a new email in Outlook 2007 (click "Check Names" to resolve the addresses.)
2. Run the SortRecipients macro. (Recipients are now sorted)
3. Delete one recipient, re-run the SortRecipients macro.
4. After doing this, I still have 4 recipients (the deleted one returns).

Comment: I use outlook 2010 and your code works without problems (except for an odd 'end if' below recipientToList.Add myRecipient.Name that is probably a leftover from copying your code excerpt and causes a compile error.

Comment: @eddy, fixed the code. Added tag for Outlook 2007. I am trying this on Outlook 2007, which is where it needs to work. Did you delete a recipient, and re-sort? It sorts fine, just re-adds the deleted recipients when running again after the sort.

Comment: Yes I sorted, removed and ran macros again. It worked for me. Don't have 2007 around anymore so can try it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and **should**) add an `Option Explicit`, Outlook would have told you that `myRecipients` was not declared at the begining of your code.

I added:

```
Dim myRecipients As Recipients
```

**[EDIT]** That wasn't enough to get the `To` field refreshed. I tried several things but eventually, i added a `.CurrentItem.Save` instead of your try of `.CurrentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll`

I think i made it work this way on my Outlook 2007.

Comment: I agree that you should add option explicit but if you don't then not declaring variables is allowed. Anything not declared is automatically declared as Object. Can you reproduce the error on 2007 if you remove the option explicit and don't declare recipients?

Comment: @JMax, I added the dim statement, but my code still has the same issue, I have updated the question to show my steps to reproduce the error

Comment: ok, i understand better and thanks to the steps you described i was able to reproduce. Seems like the `To` field is not refreshed. I found a workaround, i'll edit my post to describe it